# Between Query is not working

Tags: database

My query is like so:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nid as id,created as start,title
          FROM node WHERE (created BETWEEN '1430134906' AND '1430129127')");

 foreach ($result as $record) {
  print_r($record);exit;
 }
```

But it's not working in Drupal 7 running on MS SQL and using the [Drupal 7 driver for SQL Server and SQL Azure](https://www.drupal.org/project/sqlsrv) module. Here's an excerpt of that module's project page:

> Drupal 7 driver for Microsoft SQL Server database engines. It supports both SQL Server (version 2008 and later), and SQL Azure, part of Microsoft Azure cloud platform.

Comment: I just suggested an edit to make this question AbitMORE accurate (hope that gets accepted at least). However "it's not working" is not really helpful to understand what the actual question is. Moreover, this question does not even include a real question (not even a "?" ...). So consider enhancing your question accordingliy. Like: do you get some error msg? Do you not get any results back? Did you checking any logfiles anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a situation where Drupal's `db_select()` wrapper might be more useful. I've definitely found it readable, if all you're trying to get is an array of nids.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
                ->fields('nid')
                ->condition('created', array('1430134906', '1430129127'), 'BETWEEN');

$nids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
```

This is based on the assumption that db_select() properly wraps MSSQL, which I haven't looked into.